# Android : Unable to integrate Drawer navigation because already calling extends for Google-Maps

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-fragments, multiple-inheritance

I am working on an Android project in which I would like to add Drawer functionality, for which I already have classes and all ready.

THe problem is the Drawer code works by `extends` or extending the class which wants to add a drawer, and similarly my GoogleMaps code works in the same way. But because of Multiple-inheritance, I cannot extend 2 classes.

What should I do?

Google-maps code :

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    GoogleMap googleMap;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    int locationCount = 0;

    private RestaurantServiceImpl restaurantService = new RestaurantServiceImpl();

    List<RestRestaurant> restRestaurantList = new ArrayList<>();

    GPSTracker gps;

    double longitude, latitude;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mapsact);

        SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        // Getting GoogleMap object from the fragment
        googleMap = fm.getMap();

        // Enabling MyLocation Layer of Google Map
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        // Opening the sharedPreferences object
        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("location", 0);

        // Getting number of locations already stored
        locationCount = sharedPreferences.getInt("locationCount", 0);


        // Getting stored zoom level if exists else return 0
        String zoom = sharedPreferences.getString("zoom", "12");

        gps = new GPSTracker(MapsActivity.this);

        if (gps.canGetLocation()) {
            longitude = gps.getLongitude();
            latitude = gps.getLatitude();
            restRestaurantList = this.restaurantService.getRestaurantsByLocation(longitude,latitude);

            double lat=0, longi=0;
            for(RestRestaurant restRestaurant : restRestaurantList){
                drawMarker(new LatLng(restRestaurant.getLatitude(),restRestaurant.getLongitude()), restRestaurant.getRestaurantName(), restRestaurant.getRestaurantId());
                lat = restRestaurant.getLatitude();
                longi = restRestaurant.getLongitude();
            }

            googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(lat,longi)));

            // Setting the zoom level in the map on last position  is clicked
            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(Float.parseFloat(zoom)));

        } else {
            gps.showSettingsAlert();
        }

        googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                int restoId = Integer.valueOf(marker.getSnippet());
                Intent intent = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, MenuCardList.class);
                intent.putExtra("restaurantid", restoId);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
```

This class I need to extend to add a drawer :

```
public class DrawerLoader extends Activity {

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    // nav drawer title
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

    // used to store app title
    private CharSequence mTitle;



    private ArrayList<DrawerModel> navDrawerItems;
    private DrawerListAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.drawerlayout);


    }
    public void set(String[] navMenuTitles, TypedArray navMenuIcons) {
        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);
        navMenuIcons = getResources()
                .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);
        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<DrawerModel>();
```

If any more information is required, kindly let me know.

Comment: There is a simpler way to get a (simple) [navigation drawer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html).

Comment: @Amy : The problem is onClicking the contents, I am starting an Intent, don't know how to do that with XML. Can you please give me an example, I am new to Android. Thanks

Comment: The navigation drawer should not be an activity, it should be a fragment, which can slide into the screen and provide menu actions - is this your requirement?

Comment: @Amy : Yes, I have posted both the adapters and the other method in pastebin : http://pastebin.com/RqSWh4ye  . Can you please have a look and tell me what changes should I make. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring all your work regarding a navigation drawer, this would be my preferred solution, since There is no need for a extra Fragment, List filling, new classes....

1, Create a `nav_menu.xml` (in menues folder):

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group
        android:checkableBehavior="single">

        <item
            android:id="@+id/drawer_home"
            android:checked="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_home_black_24dp"
            android:title="Home"/>

        <item
            android:id="@+id/drawer_favourite"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_favorite_black_24dp"
            android:title="Favourites"/>

        <item
            android:id="@+id/drawer_settings"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_black_24dp"
            android:title="Settings"/>

</group>
```

2, Wrap your activites layout with a `DrawerLayout`:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!-- Your activity layout here-->

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
    app:menu="@menu/nav_menu"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

3, Update your activities java code:

```
//If you have a toolbar (recommended!)
final Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

if (actionBar != null) {
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); 
}

//and finally the Navigation View Code:
final NavigationView navigation = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
navigation.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
            navigation.setCheckedItem(menuItem.getItemId());
            drawerLayout.closeDrawers();

            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.drawer_home:
                    //open fragment home
                    return true;
                case R.id.drawer_favourite:
                    //open fragment favourite
                    return true;
                case R.id.nav_drawer_channels:
                    showFragment(2);
                    return true;
                case R.id.drawer_settings:
                    //open settings
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this,
            drawerLayout,
            toolbar,
            R.string.drawer_open, //simply a String "open"
            R.string.drawer_close) {  //simply a String "close"
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerLayout);
            drawerToggle.syncState();
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerLayout);
            drawerToggle.syncState();
        }
    };

    drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
    drawerToggle.syncState();  

    //And, last but not least, open the drawer with a Click on 'home'
   @Override
   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
       switch (item.getItemId()) {
           case android.R.id.home:
               drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
           return true;
}

return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

And you are done! No messing with extra fragment, unnecessary and messy code.

Comment: Can you please check these errors : http://s5.postimg.org/j0rjzrgqv/Screenshot_from_2015_11_30_16_07_41.png   and http://postimg.org/image/lw4n6mkqr/   . The R not found started after this. Project clean is not working.

Comment: I cannot add that design library you gave. It is too problematic, it's finding some strings somewhere and complaining its already defined and what not. Also the DrawerToggle is from some other library. 2 libraries for one drawer which already works for other classes seems too much. Can't you just tell me how to use my own code and get around this problem? Thank you.

Comment: I didn't give you any design library - just some simply to implement code. Drawers are not designed to be acitivites, they should be fragments as I mentioned above. Forgot to delete the `drawerHeader`line, but this only refers to a layout.xml. Check your folder for your nav_menu/source path.

Comment: The NavigationView is part of Android design library, I checked. And DrawerToggle is unknown. Can you elaborate on how I can go for an alternative.

Comment: See [here](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) for more information.

Comment: `drawerToggle`  is type of `ActionBarDrawerToggle` - my fault, sorry. I changed it above. But believe me - this is the most simple way to integrate navigation.